# Securely build a list of trusted CAs

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Some distributions of the cURL bundle include a utility [`mk-ca-bundle.pl`](http://curl.haxx.se/cvssource/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl) which compiles a `ca-bundle.crt` from Mozilla's root certificate store for use as a list of trusted authorities. The script prints the [following warnings](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl#L145):

> 1. Using http is subject to man in the middle attack of certdata content
> 2. Default to 'release', but more recent updates may be found in other trees
> 3. certdata.txt file format may change, lag time to update this script
> 4. Generally unwise to blindly trust CAs without manual review & verification
> 5. Mozilla apps use additional security checks aren't represented in certdata
> 6. Use of this script will make a security engineer grind his teeth and swear at you

Exactly what is the concern referenced by #4 and how can I compile an updated version of `ca-bundle.crt` securely?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. Are you looking for a replacement for `mk-ca-bundle.pl`? If so, would you want it to have different functionality or would the old functionality be fine? If different, what would you want to be different.

Comment: I just downloaded cURL and the script came in the download package. Why do you say it has been discontinued?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I'd want a way to compile a ca-bundle from an authenticated source (mk-ca-bundle just assumes the certdata it gets is authentic). I've updated the question wrt the second question.

Comment: Do you have a link to text explaining why it was discontinued? That might be helpful?

Comment: @NeilSmithline It's stated in the post: "there is no way to authenticate the certdata received by the tool". Not ideal to be trusting something you never had the opportunity to authenticate.

Comment: Yes. I read the OP. But I downloaded cURL from the definitive site, curl.haxx.se, and it contained the `mk-ca-bundle.pl` file. So I'm asking where you read that there's a security problem with the script.

Comment: Voting to close as premise of script being deprecated has not been backed up by evidence.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It's not the integrity of the script that's in question, it's the integrity of the certdata it gets from Mozilla. The script just assumed the data is authentic and builds the bundle from it.

Comment: Do you have a reference to that? It's hard to answer your question without more info.

Comment: @NeilSmithline The author of the scripts includes a warning of this very concern: https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl#L145.

I must admit I'm a bit surprised by the response here, even taking into account the poor wording of my question - do the commenters here generally believe that using this script would be wise under really any circumstances?

Comment: That link is very helpful.  I've modified the question and will nominate it for reopening.

Comment: Gary - I hope that I've kept the spirit of your question with my edit. Based on the comments, I believe that what you care about is getting a secure version of the crt file and I tried to focus the question on that.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Very nice approach to the question, and you understand my needs perfectly. My apologies again for my poorly worded original question. May I also commend you on the constructive way you handled all this, helpfulness to this degree is not often seen on some of the larger StackExchanges these days.

Comment: Not a problem. Q&A sometimes requires some interaction. That's what comments are for. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The concern is that each CA included has the organizational power to break your security, and will use that under different and hard to predict circumstance.  The "manual review" step is intended as a reminder that you need to have some process or criteria of which CAs you want to include.

What exactly that should include is subject to ongoing debate by experts.

For example, Google's review process has caused them to kick out a subset of Symantec's certificates.  (https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ro/2015/12/proactive-measures-in-digital.html).  Another example is Tor not trusting CyberRoam  (https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/ca-certificates)  Microsoft essentially outsources the decision to a group called the CA Browser Forum.

So there is not a specific list of steps you can take in #4 that will satisfy #6.